# I was sharing an iCloud account, would he know about my photos?

Tags: icloud, iphone, photo-stream

So I was sharing an  iCloud's account with person I know and lately I took some photos which I later regretted taking.   So I deleted them immediately from my iPhone and I deactivated my iCloud photo library, my photostream and my iCloud photo sharing. Then, I logged out and made my own new account.

I am worried that this person has access to my photos even though I deleted them, because I know it's possible to  recover deleted photos from iCloud.

It is possible for him to recover the photos? Should I be worried?

Comment: If he for example tries to recover his deleted photos will he recover mine too? Since we were using the same account?

Comment: One more thing. If it turns out he can recover my photos, what can I do to stop his access to my photos?

Comment: Please read http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing to understand the idea behind allowing anybody to edit posts for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you deleted the photos, then went into the Recently Deleted folder and permanently deleted them from your iPhone, followed by disabling iCloud Photo Library as you stated, then you should be fine.

Comment: Yes I did, thank you for answering! The same goes for deleted videos right?

Comment: @Hannah As long as you followed the steps, yep.